# Grails custom Application Context holder

Tags: grails, configuration, static, javabeans

I would like to access the Grails ConfigObject from within a static method and I tried to follow this article:
http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1017

The solution suggests to create a custom Application Context holder using a singleton class and register that in the beans list (resources.groovy).

The singleton class should have a private attribute of type ApplicationContext that should be initialized by the setApplicationContext method but it looks like that never happens.

How can I set ApplicationContext in my singleton class instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends when you are trying to access it - if your static method is called before the grailsApplication has been fully set up then it may not yet have been injected. Try using `grails.util.Holders` (the non-deprecated replacement for ApplicationHolder et al) or try the ["domain class trick"](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=993)

```
new MyDomainObject().getDomainClass().grailsApplication.config
```

Comment: Ian, thanks for the reply. I didn't know about the Holders class. Can you provide an example on how to use that to retrieve the ConfigObject?

Comment: @FabrizioD'Ammassa just say `Holders.config` where you would previously have used `ConfigurationHolder.config`.